# @file_get_contents fails with url

Tags: php, url, web-crawler, file-get-contents

Currently, I'm trying to code a crawler to retrieve information on websites.

When I want to retrieve the code of an web page, `@file_get_contents` fails.
The code is:

```
public function postInfos()
{
   $url = Session::get('urlMember');
   $page = @file_get_contents($url);
   $crawler = new Crawler($page);
   $fullName = $crawler->filter('span[class="full-name"]')->text();
   $fonction = $crawler->filter('#headline p[class="title"]')->text();
   return view('/data');
}
```

I tried using cURL but in this case the GET request returns nothing. Then, is there an alternative or a solution ?

Comment: what do you mean by fails ? any error you seeing? is error reporting turned on ?

Comment: Can you remove the @ before file_get_contents ? After this, what error appear?

Comment: first, the error is : InvalidArgumentException in Crawler.php line 94:
Expecting a DOMNodeList or DOMNode instance, an array, a string, or null, but got "boolean". This is because the file_get_contents malfunction. And when I remove @ : file_get_contents(https://www.linkedin.com/in/barackobama): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 999 Request denied

Comment: Your web server allows file_get_contents with an URL ? It's strange, it's not allowing the request. That's why it fails.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in comments, It seems your web server (or something) is not allowing you to make URL requests with file_get_contents. I think the best way to do this is with cURL. (I know you tried, but try the code bellow):

```
<?php
    $curl_handle=curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL,'http://linkedin.com/in/barackobama');
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $query = curl_exec($curl_handle);
    curl_close($curl_handle);

    var_dump($query);

?>
```

Please tell us the content of `var_dump($query);`

Comment: Of course, the content of `var_dump($query);` is `string (956) " "`. Then I have `Page not found`.